# Can't set headers after they are sent error in express

Tags: node.js, express

I've the following 3 files. My error is "*Can't set headers after they are sent*". I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) but I cant figure out which function or callback is causing a write to the headers after they are sent. I've spent immense time on it. please help.

routes.js

```
"use strict";
var controller = require("./controller");

module.exports = function(app){

  app.post('/master', function(req, res) {
    controller.process(req, function(err, data) {
      if( err ) { 
        return res.sendStatus(400);
      } else {
         res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    });// cb ends here
  });// process ends here
}// route ends here
```

controller.js

```
module.exports.process = function(req, cb){
  var jsonBody = req.body;
  var type = jsonBody["strType"]; 
  var id = jsonBody["id"];
  var moment = require('moment');

  if ( !type || !id ) {
    return (cb(true, false));
  }

  if( type === "company" ) {
    Company_strCode = jsonBody["Company_strCode"];  
    jsonBody.lastUpdate = moment().format();
    delete jsonBody["strType"];
    delete jsonBody["id"];
    dbOps.companyUpsert(type, Company_strCode, jsonBody, cb);
    dbOps.normalUpsert(type, id, jsonBody, cb);
    return;
  }

  jsonBody.lastUpdate = moment().format();
  delete jsonBody["strType"];
  delete jsonBody["id"];

  dbOps.normalUpsert( type, id, jsonBody, cb );
} //fnProcess ends
```

dbOps.js

```
"use strict";
var keyDef = require('../config/config.json')

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var host = keyDef.mongodb.host; 
var port = keyDef.mongodb.port;
var db = keyDef.mongodb.db;
var username = keyDef.mongodb.username;
var password = keyDef.mongodb.password;
var url = "mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/"+db;

module.exports.normalUpsert = function(type, id, jsonBody, cb){

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
        if(err){
            console.log("Mongodb connection error..");
            return cb(true, false);
        }

        db.collection(type).update({"_id":id},{$set:(jsonBody)}, {upsert:true}, function(err){
            if(err){
                return cb(true, false);
            }
            cb(false, true);
        });//func callback
    });// mongoClient callback
};

module.exports.companyUpsert = function(type, Company_strCode, jsonBody, cb){

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Mongodb connection error..");
            return cb(true, false);
        }
        db.collection("Cinema").update({"Cinema_strCompanyCode":Company_strCode},{$set:{"tblCompany":jsonBody}}, {upsert:true}, function(err){
            if(err){
                return cb(true, false);
            }
            cb(false, true);
        });//func callback
    });// mongoClient callback
};
```

Comment: You don't need to return tag in controller, just use callback function without return tag! and don't use return tag anywhere in controller just use callback function!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `if ( type === "company" )` condition, you are calling cb 2 times, causing res.sendStatus to be called 2 times a well. Try a workaround like this if it works for you...

```
module.exports.process = function(req, cb){
  var jsonBody = req.body;
  var type = jsonBody["strType"]; 
  var id = jsonBody["id"];
  var moment = require('moment');

  if ( !type || !id ) {
    return (cb(true, false));
  }

  if( type === "company" ) {
    Company_strCode = jsonBody["Company_strCode"];  
    jsonBody.lastUpdate = moment().format();
    delete jsonBody["strType"];
    delete jsonBody["id"];
    dbOps.companyUpsert(type, Company_strCode, jsonBody, function (err, data){
      if (err)
        return (cb(true, false));
      else
        dbOps.normalUpsert(type, id, jsonBody, cb);
    });
    return;
  }

  jsonBody.lastUpdate = moment().format();
  delete jsonBody["strType"];
  delete jsonBody["id"];

  dbOps.normalUpsert( type, id, jsonBody, cb );
} //fnProcess ends
```

or I would prefer something like this :

```
module.exports.process = function(req, cb){
  var jsonBody = req.body;
  var type = jsonBody["strType"]; 
  var id = jsonBody["id"];
  var moment = require('moment');

  if ( !type || !id ) {
    return (cb(true, false));
  }

  jsonBody.lastUpdate = moment().format();
  delete jsonBody["strType"];
  delete jsonBody["id"];

  if( type === "company" ) {
    Company_strCode = jsonBody["Company_strCode"];  
    dbOps.companyUpsert(type, Company_strCode, jsonBody, function (err, data){
      if (err)
        return (cb(true, false));
    });
  }

  dbOps.normalUpsert( type, id, jsonBody, cb );
} //fnProcess ends
```